# Getting "System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: apex, approval-process, exception

below is method which i have created  in my class,

```
  public static void rejectCRF(String recordId, String workItemId, String comments) {
    Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
    req2.setComments(comments);
    req2.setAction('Reject');
    req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {recordId});

    // Use the ID from the newly created item to specify the item to be worked 
    req2.setWorkitemId(workItemId);

    // Submit the request for approval 
    **Approval.ProcessResult result2 =  Approval.process(req2);**

    // Verify the results 
    System.assert(result2.isSuccess(), 'Result Status:'+result2.isSuccess());

    System.assertEquals(
        'Rejected', result2.getInstanceStatus(), 
        'Instance Status'+result2.getInstanceStatus()
    );
    List<Approval_Request__c> lstApprovalReq = [select Id from Approval_Request__c where Record_Id__c =:recordId];
    for(Approval_Request__c appReq : lstApprovalReq) {
        appReq.Status__c = 'Rejected';
    }
    if(!lstApprovalReq.isEmpty()) {
        update lstApprovalReq;
    }
}
```

line marked in bold getting the error...could you please suggest me how i am getting this error or any solution on this...

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this error is, the record that you are trying to submit for approval does not match entry criteria conditions of the approval process. For example, entry criteria is "status= not approved" then you need to add the same condition in your code before submitting for approval

Comment: I will try with mentioned way by you...if you have any other solution please let me know...